# libgdx dispose sprites from textureatlas

Tags: android, libgdx, dispose, texture-atlas

If I call `sprite.getTexture().dispose();` on a `Texture` which was retrieved from an `TextureAtlas` the whole screen becomes black.

```
public class PlayState extends State {
   // The falling objects from the sky
   private Array<FallingObject> objects;

   private AssetManager assetManager;
   private TextureAtlas textureAtlas;

   private Sprite background;

   public PlayState() {
      assetManager = new AssetManager();
      assetManager.load("assets.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
      assetManager.finishLoading();
      textureAtlas = assetManager.get("assets.pack");

      background = new Sprite(textureAtlas.get("background"));

      // Add some falling objects
      objects.add(new FallingObject(textureAtlas.findRegion("kitty")));
      objects.add(new FallingObject(textureAtlas.findRegion("leaf")));
      ojbects.add(new FallingObject(textureAtlas.findRegion("dog")));
   }

   @Override
   public void update(float deltaTime) {
      for (FallingObject object : objects) {
         object.update(deltaTime);

         if (object.reachedBottom()) {
            object.dispose(); // <------------ THIS CAUSES THE ERROR
            objects.remove(object);

            objects.add(new FallingObject(textureAtlas.findRegion(getRandomRegionName()));
         }
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
      batch.begin();

      // Draw the background
      background.draw(batch);

      // Draw the falling objects
      for (FallingObject object : objects) {
         batch.draw(object.getSprite(), object.position.x, object.position.y);
      }

      batch.end();
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
      assetManager.dispose();
      textureAtlas.dipose();

      for (FallingObject object : objects) {
         object.dispose();
      }
   }

}
```

The falling object

```
public class FallingObject extends GameObject {
    private Sprite sprite;

    public FallingObject(TextureRegion region) {
       sprite = new Sprite(region);
    }

    public void dispose() {
       sprite.getTexture().dispose(); // <-- HERE, when this is called, the whole screen becomes black
    }
}
```

I have managed to solve the problem, by not calling `dispose` on the `texture` retrieved from the `sprite` in the `FallingObject` class. I am clearing the reference by declaring `NULL` the sprite:

```
public class FallingObject extends GameObject {
   private Sprite sprite;

   public void dispose() {
      sprite = null;
   }
}
```

But now I am afraid of Memory Leaks! Is this the right approach to dispose the Sprites?

Comment: I believe `sprite.getTexture()` fetches the complete atlas and thus if you call dispose it disposes the complete atlas. Anyway, you have to see a atlas differently I think. I use a atlas for every tileset I have. If a level needs a specific tileset it will load it and dispose when the level closes. My gui atlas will always remain in memory as long as the game is running since it's almost always needed.

Comment: Also you are looking up textures from your atlas in your update method. `.findRegion` is a relative expansive method. You should avoid using it in your update loop. Likewise the `new` keyword should be avoided in the update loop. Object initialization is expensive too. You are much better off using a pool of falling objects and reuse these objects.

Answer (score 3):

Sprites from a texture atlas all share the same texture, so you must not dispose of that texture until you are completely done with any sprite that derives from that texture atlas.

Sprites do not implement Disposable, so that is a clue that you do not need to worry about disposing individual sprites. Setting them to null is fine, but the texture they derive from does eventually need to be disposed when you're done with it.

Also, anything that is loaded via an AssetManager should not be disposed directly. Instead, you should call `assetManager.unload(myDisposableObject);` so it can be properly tracked by the asset manager. Or you can call `assetManager.dispose()` if you are completely done with all objects that were loaded with that asset manager.

Comment: Listen to this guy and accept his answer, he is 100% correct.